# how to unit test a Qt application with QtTest using subdirs

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qmake

I found a few other hits when searching for this particular problem, but i cant get my setup to work with my unit test project(s).

> project info: ( optional reading)
>
> I am in the beginning of my final undergraduate project, where I am to
>   create an IDE for the language Promula and the the
>   verification tool Spin. The professor I am doing this with expects to
>   use it in his classes and for future undergraduates to keep improving. It is also meant to be a open source project everyone can contribute to.

[Spin tool](http://spinroot.com)

my folder struture:

```
QSpin
-QSpin.pro
-QSpinApplication
--QSpinapplication.pro
--QSpinApplication.pri
--include
---Workspace
----*.h
--src
---Workspace
----*.cpp
-QSpinApplicationTests
--QSpinApplicationTests.pro
--WorkspaceGroupTests
---WorkspaceGroupTests.pro
----some cpp testfile
```

My QSpinApplication compiles and runs without any problems. The import of what i have so can be imported.

```
#include <Workspace/(file_name).h>
```

However in my test project WorkspaceGroupTests i want to include headers in the same way, but i cant get it to work. Beside that i assume the test project need to know where the cpp files are. If i dont use any of the application headers the test project compiles and runs with the default test case.
at the moment i am using a default shadow build with its root folder in the QSpin folder.

> Any idea of how i get my test project working correctly, to actual be able to test my application classes?

QSpin.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS += \
    QSpinApplication\QSpinApplication.pro \
    QSpinApplicationTests
```

QSpinApplication.pro:

```
QT += quick qml gui
CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES +=src/main.cpp
include(QSpinApplication.pri)
RESOURCES += qml.qrc

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

QSpinApplication.pri:

```
#//DEPENDPATH += $$PWD
INCLUDEPATH += ./include
SOURCES +=src/workspace/workspaceview.cpp \
    src/workspace/groupitem.cpp \
    src/workspace/groupitemsplitter.cpp \
    src/workspace/workspacegroup.cpp \
    src/workspace/workspaceviewattached.cpp \
    src/workspace/workspaceviewiteminfo.cpp \
    src/workspace/workspacegrouplinknode.cpp

HEADERS += \
    include/workspace/workspaceview.h \
    include/workspace/groupitem.h \
    include/workspace/groupitemsplitter.h \
    include/workspace/workspacegroup.h \
    include/workspace/workspaceviewattached.h \
    include/workspace/workspace.h \
    include/workspace/workspaceviewiteminfo.h \
    include/workspace/workspacegrouplinknode.h
```

QSpinApplicationTests.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += \
    WorkspaceGroupTests
```

WorkspaceGroupTests.pro:

```
QT += testlib
QT -= gui
DEPENDPATH+=./../../QSpinApplication
include(./../../QSpinApplication/QSpinApplication.pri)
CONFIG += qt console warn_on depend_includepath testcase
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES +=  tst_workspacegrouptests.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood well but in general, what I would advise is to create a separate structure for "lib" where you put logic code that can be tested, so default structure would look like that:

```
Structure:
 ├───app.pro
 ├───lib.pro
 └───tests.pro
```

Then you put in your lib.pro:

```
TARGET = NameOfTarget
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
```

and add in your tests.pro, and in app.pro:

```
LIBS += -L../lib -lNameOfTarget
```

At end it should be possible without problems to include in app directory and in test:

`#include "anyHeaderFromLib.h"` .

Comment: I followed your instructions to the letter and the compiler complains ":-1: error: cannot find -lNameOfTarget"

Answer (score 0):

As an extra addition for Michal Kalinowski answer:

Looks like this will work only for Linux/Mac, in case of Windows you should handle it on that way:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L../lib/debug -lNameOfTarget
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += --L../lib/release -lNameOfTarget
else:unix: LIBS += -L../lib -lNameOfTarget
```

Some more context can be get here: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html